# Grub says GRUB GRUB GRUB GRUB

Tags: grub2

I recently uninstalled Ubuntu to install Ubuntu mate, but when I go to install Ubuntu mate nothing shows up besides GRUB GRUB GRUB GRUB. I was wondering if someone could help. Just to be specific I DO NOT have ubuntu on my computer I am using Windows 8.1 trying to install Ubuntu mate 16.04. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this error can be caused by your computer's BIOS detecting disks (such as the Ubuntu MATE installation USB or DVD) incorrectly.

Could you please reboot into your computer's BIOS settings (usually by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>DELETE</kbd> while your computer is booting) and see if there are any options along the lines of "Automatically Detect Disks" or "USB disk format"? If there is an option to manually set the USB disk type, you can choose that.

Another possible cause is simply that the GRUB bootloader is corrupted; you could try re-downloading Ubuntu MATE and create a new startup DVD/USB. (What software did you use or what steps did follow to create your current Ubuntu MATE installation media?)